# In Riesz's Representation theorem: $\langle x,\cdot\rangle$ or $\langle\cdot,x\rangle$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

In Riesz's Representation theorem, we're able to identify a functional $L\in H^*$ with the inner product ($\langle\cdot , \cdot\rangle$) of an element $h \in H$.

But is there a difference if I do $Lx=\langle x,h\rangle$ or $Lx=\langle h,x\rangle$ ?

I'm reading a book on PDE (Sandro Salsa's) and on page 378 they state the theorem with $Lx=\langle h,x\rangle$.

However, they later use this version of Riesz theorem to justify the definition of the adjoint as $\langle Lx,y\rangle=\langle x,L^*y\rangle$.

However, using the Riesz theorem from Salsa's book will tell us $Lx=\langle L^*y,x\rangle$ instead.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Proper notation is $\langle h,x\rangle,$ not $<h,x>$, and $\langle \cdot,x\rangle$ rather than $\langle .,x\rangle.$ I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functional corresponding to $h \in H$ is $$L_h :x \mapsto \langle x,h \rangle.$$

Over $\mathbb{C}$ it can't be the other one as the inner product is NOT linear in the second variable. (It is antilinear, $\langle \cdot, a x \rangle = \overline{a} \langle \cdot, x \rangle$). But over $\mathbb{R}$ the inner product is symmetric, so it does not matter.

Comment: Many thanks! ;) (I'll accept your answer in 5 mins, due to site restrictions)